# Toggle inputs readonly explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, readonly

I wanted to toggle all input's readonly attribute in a Div.
I have found a few solutions but only one worked.

I would like to know why this code doesn't work:

```
$("#" + id + " :input").each( function() {
       $(this).readOnly = !$(this).readOnly;
});
```

This is the working code:

```
$("#" + id + " :input").each( function() {
    (this).attr("disabled", function(i, d) {
      return !d;   
    });
});
```

Can anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugguyqoj/)

We can use jquery prop to toggle readonly attriblute.

HTML:

```
<input  type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Toggle" />
<div id="divToggle">
  <label>First:</label><input type="text" id="txtFirst" /><br/>
  <label>Second:</label><input type="text" id="txtSecond" /><br/>
  <label>Third:</label><input type="text" id="txtThird" /><br/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btnToggle").click(function(){
  var id="divToggle";
  $("#" + id + " :input").each( function() {
      $(this).prop("readOnly",!$(this).prop("readOnly"));
  });
});
```